# vi mode visual selection in zsh on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, zsh, vi

I use zhs in vi mode on my WSL install, however for whatever reason the Windows terminal disables visual selection in the shell. Whenever I press `v` the system just plays the error bell, which makes editing commands quite annoying. I thought this was controlled by the "Insert Mode" tickbox in the terminal properties, however that doesn't fix it.

How do I enable visual selection in WSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your ~/.zshrc:

```
function vi-yank-xclip {
    zle vi-yank
    echo "$CUTBUFFER" | /mnt/c/windows/system32/clip.exe
}
zle -N vi-yank-xclip
bindkey -M vicmd 'y' vi-yank-xclip
```

Based on the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61466461/yank-in-visual-vim-mode-in-zsh-does-not-copy-to-clipboard-in-ordert-to-paste-w)